# Arduino Piccolo Example Script Error

Tags: arduino-uno, c++

So I am trying to make an audio visualizer from this tutorial listed [here.](https://learn.adafruit.com/piccolo/overview)

So I downloaded all the files needed, and downloaded the code. But when I try to verify it, I get this Error:

```
C:\Users\ted\Desktop\Arduino_Sandbox_Windows_01\Arduino\libraries\Robot_Control\ArduinoRobot.cpp: In constructor 'RobotControl::RobotControl()':
C:\Users\ted\Desktop\Arduino_Sandbox_Windows_01\Arduino\libraries\Robot_Control\ArduinoRobot.cpp:8: error: 'LCD_CS' was not declared in this scope
C:\Users\ted\Desktop\Arduino_Sandbox_Windows_01\Arduino\libraries\Robot_Control\ArduinoRobot.cpp:8: error: 'DC_LCD' was not declared in this scope
C:\Users\ted\Desktop\Arduino_Sandbox_Windows_01\Arduino\libraries\Robot_Control\ArduinoRobot.cpp:8: error: 'RST_LCD' was not declared in this scope
C:\Users\ted\Desktop\Arduino_Sandbox_Windows_01\Arduino\libraries\Robot_Control\ArduinoRobot.cpp: In member function 'void RobotControl::begin()':
C:\Users\ted\Desktop\Arduino_Sandbox_Windows_01\Arduino\libraries\Robot_Control\ArduinoRobot.cpp:18: error: 'MUXA' was not declared in this scope
C:\Users\ted\Desktop\Arduino_Sandbox_Windows_01\Arduino\libraries\Robot_Control\ArduinoRobot.cpp:18: error: 'MUXB' was not declared in this scope
C:\Users\ted\Desktop\Arduino_Sandbox_Windows_01\Arduino\libraries\Robot_Control\ArduinoRobot.cpp:18: error: 'MUXC' was not declared in this scope
C:\Users\ted\Desktop\Arduino_Sandbox_Windows_01\Arduino\libraries\Robot_Control\ArduinoRobot.cpp:18: error: 'MUXD' was not declared in this scope
C:\Users\ted\Desktop\Arduino_Sandbox_Windows_01\Arduino\libraries\Robot_Control\ArduinoRobot.cpp:19: error: 'MUX_IN' was not declared in this scope
C:\Users\ted\Desktop\Arduino_Sandbox_Windows_01\Arduino\libraries\Robot_Control\ArduinoRobot.cpp:22: error: 'BUZZ' was not declared in this scope
C:\Users\ted\Desktop\Arduino_Sandbox_Windows_01\Arduino\libraries\Robot_Control\ArduinoRobot.cpp:25: error: 'Serial1' was not declared in this scope
core.a(main.cpp.o): In function `main':
C:\Users\ted\Desktop\Arduino_Sandbox_Windows_01\Arduino\hardware\arduino\cores\arduino/main.cpp:11: undefined reference to `setup'
C:\Users\ted\Desktop\Arduino_Sandbox_Windows_01\Arduino\hardware\arduino\cores\arduino/main.cpp:14: undefined reference to `loop'
```

I've looked this up before, and couldn't find anything on it. So I came here for a last resort.

### Any ideas?

EDIT: So I reinstalled the folders, and renamed the LED folder but now I get a new error:

Piccolo:112: error: 'Adafruit_BicolorMatrix' does not name a type
Piccolo.pde: In function 'void setup()':
Piccolo:130: error: 'matrix' was not declared in this scope
Piccolo.pde: In function 'void loop()':
Piccolo:168: error: 'matrix' was not declared in this scope
Piccolo:168: error: 'LED_RED' was not declared in this scope
Piccolo:169: error: 'LED_YELLOW' was not declared in this scope
Piccolo:170: error: 'LED_GREEN' was not declared in this scope
Piccolo:207: error: 'LED_OFF' was not declared in this scope
Piccolo:210: error: 'LED_OFF' was not declared in this scope

EDIT 2: Deleted Robot_Control and got this error:

In file included from Piccolo.pde:34:
C:\Users\ted\Desktop\Arduino_Sandbox_Windows_01\Arduino\libraries\Adafruit_LEDBackpack/Adafruit_LEDBackpack.h:94: error: expected class-name before '{' token
C:\Users\ted\Desktop\Arduino_Sandbox_Windows_01\Arduino\libraries\Adafruit_LEDBackpack/Adafruit_LEDBackpack.h:103: error: expected class-name before '{' token
C:\Users\ted\Desktop\Arduino_Sandbox_Windows_01\Arduino\libraries\Adafruit_LEDBackpack/Adafruit_LEDBackpack.h:112: error: expected class-name before '{' token
Piccolo.pde: In function 'void loop()':
Piccolo:168: error: 'class Adafruit_BicolorMatrix' has no member named 'fillRect'
Piccolo:169: error: 'class Adafruit_BicolorMatrix' has no member named 'fillRect'
Piccolo:170: error: 'class Adafruit_BicolorMatrix' has no member named 'fillRect'
Piccolo:207: error: 'class Adafruit_BicolorMatrix' has no member named 'drawLine'
Piccolo:210: error: 'class Adafruit_BicolorMatrix' has no member named 'drawLine'

Comment: It sounds like something is incorrectly trying to include the `Robot_Control` library. Have you made any changes to the code at all?

Comment: No I don't believe so...Do you think I should try maybe re-installing the code?

Comment: You could maybe try re-installing the IDE (and make sure you've got the latest version). Do the same with any 3rd party libraries too.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, reinstalling/updating all your 3rd party libraries to the latest versions is probably the first thing to try. Updating the IDE itself may also help.

If that hasn't worked then a forum topic here seems to describe the same kind of issue: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=168854.0

One of the users seems to have tracked the problem down to a couple of Adafruit libraries. He suggests the following:

> 1) Delete the folder "Robot_Control" from Program
>   Files\Arduino\libraries\
>
> 2) Make sure, that the two Adafruit folders in the same folder are
>   named Adafruit_GFX and Adafruit_ST7735. I had them named "AdafruitGFX"
>   and "AdafruitST7735", but that was wrong.

Deleting the `Robot_Control` folder doesn't sound like an ideal solution to me, but perhaps there's an incompatibility which can't be easily fixed. Unfortunately, the Arduino IDE handles libraries in a slightly strange way, so weird problems can happen from time to time.